How to Group 0 with NULL in mysql select
I know there are many variants of this question, but none seem to address my issue.
I have a page reporting website order stats. One of the variables it considers is which 'website' a customer used.
The website ids are integers, but for historical reasons, one of them is stored as either 0 or NULL.
I need to group them together in my query.
I know I could update all NULL entries to 0 in that row of the db, but a lot of changes would need to be made to prevent more being added.
My original query was:
SELECT o.website, p.orderid, count(p.orderid) ordercount
FROM gdd_order as o, gdd_process as p 
WHERE o.orderid = p.orderid 
AND p.prog_return >= '2024-03-01' 
AND p.prog_return < '2024-03-31'  
GROUP BY o.website 
ORDER BY FIELD(o.website,0,5,1,2,3,4)

which returns



website
orderid
ordercount




(NULL)
92914
76


0
93256
48


5
92916
74


1
92908
136



I tried:
SELECT ifnull(o.website, 0) website, p.orderid, count(p.orderid) ordercount
FROM gdd_order as o, gdd_process as p 
WHERE o.orderid = p.orderid 
AND p.prog_return >= '2024-03-01' 
AND p.prog_return < '2024-03-31'  
GROUP BY o.website 
ORDER BY FIELD(o.website,0,5,1,2,3,4)

which makes NULL zero, but doesn't group the 'null 0' row in with the '0' row:



website
orderid
ordercount




0
92914
76


0
93256
48


5
92916
74


1
92908
136



How do I combine the '0' and 'NULL 0' data in a single row?

I'm not sure it makes sense to say you want grouping by website and then include order ids in the result. That's going to force grouping on order id too I think

GROUP BY IFNULL(o.website, 0)

If you give the alias a different name from the column, you can use GROUP BY <alias>

Also use IFNULL() in the ORDER BY column.

The inclusion of p.orderid in your select list makes your query nondeterministic. Configured properly (with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled) you should be getting an error. Please read MySQL Handling of GROUP BY.

Use IFNULL(o.website, 0) consistently throughout the query.
SELECT ifnull(o.website, 0) website, p.orderid, count(p.orderid) ordercount
FROM gdd_order as o, gdd_process as p 
WHERE o.orderid = p.orderid 
AND p.prog_return >= '2024-03-01' 
AND p.prog_return < '2024-03-31'  
GROUP BY IFNULL(o.website, 0)
ORDER BY FIELD(IFNULL(o.website, 0),0,5,1,2,3,4)


friend. I think you can add this part to combine 0 and NULL
IFNULL(o.website, 0)

So, your query:
SELECT IFNULL(o.website, 0) AS website, p.orderid, COUNT(p.orderid) AS ordercount
FROM gdd_order AS o
JOIN gdd_process AS p ON o.orderid = p.orderid
WHERE p.prog_return >= '2024-03-01' AND p.prog_return < '2024-03-31'  
GROUP BY IFNULL(o.website, 0)
ORDER BY FIELD(IFNULL(o.website, 0), 0, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4);

Tell if this works with your database, we don't have sample information to prove it.

Use COALESCE() function which returns the first non-null value in a list.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce
Update your query like:
SELECT o.website, p.orderid, count(p.orderid) ordercount
FROM (SELECT COALESCE(website, 0), [OTHER COLUMS] FROM gdd_order) o, gdd_process as p 
WHERE o.orderid = p.orderid 
AND p.prog_return >= '2024-03-01' 
AND p.prog_return < '2024-03-31'  
GROUP BY o.website 
ORDER BY FIELD(o.website,0,5,1,2,3,4)

It's should work

SELECT COALESCE(website, 0), [OTHER COLUMS] FROM gdd_order;

This query will change your table from



website
orderid
ordercount




(NULL)
92914
76


0
93256
48


5
92916
74


1
92908
136



to



website
orderid
ordercount




0
92914
76


0
93256
48


5
92916
74


1
92908
136



Thank You

They're already using IFNULL(), which is the same as COALESCE() when there are only 2 arguments.

You need to assign an alias in the subquery.

Yes, you're right @Barmar.
Your approach is best...
